# Retry Jenkins Maven build if unstable?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

Might be a very basic question, but I can't seem to find any straightforward documentation on how to do it.

I have a very basic UI test that runs every couple hours, and every once in a blue moon the build is unstable because the test fails for one reason or another(finicky selenium stale elements, other anomalies). I would like it so that that the job retries the build again if it is unstable, and if it is still unstable after the second try, then send out the alert (currently using Slack notifications in the post build actions section).

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The naginator jenkins plugin allows you to rerun a build for unstable builds as well as failures.  You will have to install the plugin in jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin